# 'What ho!' of Bertie Wooster

Tags: expressions, greetings, interjections

*"What ho!"* - this strange form of greeting is used all the time by Bertie Wooster, a character of well-known "Jeeves and Wooster" stories by P. G. Wodehouse.

> Bertie Wooster: Oh, what ho, Sir Watkyn!
>
> Sir Watkyn Bassett: Kindly do not address me in that familiar way, Wooster. I happen to know 
>         that once again you've yielded to the awful temptation to steal a policeman's helmet!
>       .....
>
> Bertie Wooster: Aunt Dahlia! What ho, old blood relation!
>
> Aunt Dahlia: [affectionately] Hello, Bertie, revolting young blot.

What does *"ho"* mean in such expressions? Is it a word reduction or an idiom?

Comment: There's also "Right-ho" he uses. One of the books is titled "Right-ho, Jeeves!".

Comment: Some of these unfathomable expressions are said to have been those of King George ll, a Hanoverian who could not speak English well. He would use silly-sounding phrases like 'Hey-what'. Sycophants at court would imitate him, and that is how the expressions came into being. I am not sure if 'what-ho' is one of them, or even if it was George ll. Anyway, it was one of the Georges.

Comment: It should be remembered that Wodehouse lived most of his life in the US and was writing for a largely US audience.

Comment: @Hot Licks: But "what ho!" and similar expressions are by no means limited to Wodehouse's writing, but seem (at least from my reading) to have been fairly common expressions among (at least) young upper-class British of the period.  I'm sure you could find parallels among for instance today's urban youth.

Comment: @jamesqf - My point is that Wodehouse picked words, not because they were necessarily "faithful" representations of British speech patterns, but because they sounded comically "British" to Americans.  He had a very good ear for this, and no doubt "stretched the truth" on occasion when it suited him.  While most of the terms he used were likely heard somewhere in the British Isles at some point in the past 200 years or so, they should not be assumed to be representative of any particular segment of the British population.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I don't think Wodehouse was writing primarily for Americans.  His books were as popular in Britain as in the US (if not more so), and during the 1920s period when Jeeves & Bertie were created, he lived as much in Britain as the US.  Bertie's perhaps a humorous exaggeration of an upper-class young Briton of the period, but as far as I can tell, one drawn - like Psmith - pretty much from life.

Comment: @WS2 The phrase predates Geo II

Comment: @WS2 That would be George II, not George LL! I is 1, L is 50! Roman numerals don't allow two Ls in a single number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/books/article-2059950/What-ho-Is-Norse-youre-speaking-Bertie-Old-Bean--THE-STORY-OF-ENGLISH-IN-100-WORDS-BY-DAVID-CRYSTAL.html), "what ho" is derived from "hwaet", which is the first word of *Beowulf* and is a sign of greeting. I don't think "ho" has a meaning by itself.

Comment: It is just and interjection used as a call to attract attention or as an exclamation of surprise or delight.

Comment: Yes, more or less equivalent to *[Wassup?](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wassup)*

Comment: Ah, Bertie Wooster reciting Beowulf in Old English. Lovely image. _Hwæt Ho!_

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this is nautical in nature, deriving from "Land ho!", the traditional lookout's joyful cry on sighting land.  Bertie usually uses this in greeting, and the meaning is roughly "What's up?", or "What's going on?"  For a sailor, land is what is going on; for Bertie he doesn't know and he's asking.

Comment: Hi Woosterfan, your answer has been flagged as low-quality, possibly because it's too short or not detailed enough. At the very least, I would ask that you please edit to include a reference supporting your assertion that this is its origin, otherwise it can't be considered a **definitive** answer, which is what we look for on this site. - [From Review](http://english.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/171335)

Comment: @JohnClifford this answer was posted over a year ago, and since then the answerer has disappeared. I don't know why it's being flagged today... You could  edit the post and add references yourself, if you like.

Comment: Sorry @Mari-LouA, didn't notice the posting date.

Comment: @JohnClifford no need to apologize, someone flagged it, you're not at fault :)

Comment: I think this answer is more relevant than others

Answer (score 2):

I grew up Wednesfield, Staffordshire (near Wolverhampton, England) in the 1950s and 60s where "What ho" was a very common greeting between young working class lads although it was usually pronounced as "Worro" (often followed by "our kid"). It certainly wasn't trying to be pretentiously Shakepearean! Much more likely the utterance had simply remained in usage from pre-Shakespearean times. I've often wondered if "what ho" is itself a shortening/corruption of "What, who's this?", or if "ho" is related to "hove" (as in the nautical "hove into view").

Other common greetings were "Watcha" (l suppose short for "what are you doing/up to") and "Alright?" Although we sometimes said "Hullo" we never said "Hi" or "Hey". Grown ups would often say "how do you do?" shortened to "how do?".

Answer (score 1):

"What!" has been explained.

"Ho!" is an essential attention getter, from earlier English, but the semiotic is universal, isn't it? The most famous use is in Isaiah 55:1, King James version: "Ho, every one that thirsteth, come ye to the waters, and he that hath no money; come ye, buy, and eat; yea, come, buy wine and milk without money and without price."

In that passage, the word stems from the Hebrew, "ה֤וֹי" pronounced... "Ho!"
;-)  https://biblehub.com/text/isaiah/55-1.htm

Answer (score 0):

It's a Shakespearean reference. Try googling "what ho Othello" or "what ho apothecary".

I think it's probably intended to allude to Bertie Wooster's (presumably expensive) education and illustrate his flippant nature.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't 'ho' in this case from the middle english - meaning 'who'?

I dont have reputation to comment :(   However, the Daily Mail is an English tabloid 'newspaper' which should not be regarded as a reliable source.

Comment: The Daily Mail article is about David Crystal's book, *The Story of English in 100 Words*. He is one the most eminent and respected English linguists today.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase is far older than I imagined – over 600 years old:

OED

> **what ho, int. and adj.**
>
> A. int. **An exclamation used to call the attention of a person, or as an expression of excitement or exultation.** *Now archaic or affected.*
>
> c1405  (▸c1390)    G. Chaucer Miller's Tale (Hengwrt) (2003) l. 251   *What how, what do ye maister Nicholay.*
>
> 1579   E. Spenser Shepheardes Cal. July 5   *What ho, thou iollye shepheards swayne, Come vp the hyll to me.*

And **Ho!**:

> **ho**, int.1 and n.2
>
> A. int.1
>
> **1. An exclamation expressing, according to intonation, surprise, admiration, exultation (often ironical), triumph, taunting.**
>
> a1400  (▸a1325)    Cursor Mundi (Vesp.) l. 12129   ‘Ho!’ [Gött. O ho!] all þan cun þai cri, ‘Qua herd euer sua gret ferli’.